# When focusout but outside windows behave different if focusout inside window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I create a move placeholder, the issue is that when i blur from the element outside the window it behave different than if i blur from the element inside the window.

Note: The implementation works but that behave from the gif is only when is blur (outside chrome) but when is blur inside it behaves good.

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    @if (!reverseZipcode)
    {
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div class="input-wrapper hide-text-input"> 
                <input type="tel" data-mask="1-000-000-0000" required name="Phone" title="@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Phone", placeHolders)" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Telephone Number" />
                <span class="label-click down">@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Phone", placeHolders)</span>

            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 no-padding-left">
            <div class="input-wrapper hide-text-input">
                <input type="number" required name="Zip" title="@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Zip", placeHolders)" data-mask="00000" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Zip Code" />
                <span class="label-click down">@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Zip", placeHolders)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div class="input-wrapper hide-text-input">
                <input type="number" required name="Zip" title="@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Zip", placeHolders)" data-mask="00000" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Zip Code" />
                <span class="label-click down">@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Zip", placeHolders)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 no-padding-left">
            <div class="input-wrapper hide-text-input">
                <input type="tel" data-mask="1-000-000-0000" required name="Phone" title="@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Phone", placeHolders)" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Telephone Number" />
                <span class="label-click down">@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Phone", placeHolders)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="form-group hide-text-input">
    <input type="email" required name="Email" title="@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Email", placeHolders)" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Email Address" />
    <span class="label-click up">@Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText("Email", placeHolders)</span>
</div>


$('input[type=text],input[type=tel],[type=number],[type=email]')
  .focus(function () {
      changeLabel($(this));
  }).blur(function () {
      changeLabel($(this));
  });


function changeLabel(element) {
    if ($(element).is('input')) {
        var $label = $(element).parent().find('span.label-click')

        if ($label && $label.hasClass('down')) {
            var elmHeight = parseFloat($(element).css('height'));
            var fontSizeLabel = "12pt"
            if ((elmHeight >= 0) && (elmHeight <= 30)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "7pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "12px");
            }
            if ((elmHeight > 30) && (elmHeight <= 40)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "8pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "14px");
            }
            if ((elmHeight > 40) && (elmHeight <= 50)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "10pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "14px");
            }
            if ((elmHeight > 50)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "12pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "14px");
            }
            $label.animate({
                "top": ($(element).position().top) + parseFloat($(element).css("margin-top")) + "px",
                "padding-top": "2px",
                "left": ($(element).position().left) + "px",
                "padding-left": (parseFloat($(element).css("margin-left")) + 5) + "px",
                "font-size": fontSizeLabel
            }, 200);

            $label.removeClass("down");
            $label.addClass("up");
            return;
        } else if ($label.hasClass('up') && !$(element).val()) {

            var elmHeight = parseFloat($(element).css('height'));
            var elmWidth = parseFloat($(element).css('width'));

            var fontSizeLabel = "12pt"
            if ((elmHeight >= 0) && (elmHeight <= 30)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "8pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "12px");
            }

            if ((elmHeight > 30) && (elmHeight <= 40)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "10pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "14px");
            }
            if ((elmHeight > 40) && (elmHeight <= 50)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "12pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "16px");
            }
            if ((elmHeight > 50)) {
                fontSizeLabel = "16pt"
                $(element).css("padding-top", "16px");
            }
            topLabel = (($(element).outerHeight() / 2) - ($label.outerHeight() / 2)) + parseFloat($(element).css("margin-top")) + "px";
            $label.animate({
                "top": topLabel,
                "left": "0px",
                "padding-top": "0px",
                "padding-left": ($(element).position().left + (parseFloat($(element).css("margin-left"))) + 10) + "px",
                "font-size": fontSizeLabel,
            }, 200);
            $label.removeClass("up");
            $label.addClass("down");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Behave GIF:** https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HU8NA7QrGqcIxm8/giphy.gif

**NewB GIF: (Behavior)** https://media.giphy.com/media/xULW8r9DmQGlL4cDh6/giphy.gif

Comment: I don't understand: "The implementation works but that behave from the gif is only when is blur (outside chrome) but when is blur inside it behaves good." Could you please clarify?

Comment: @JulioPérez seems like when you click inside an element (el a), and click out of the window, and click back into the window into el b, el a quickly re-applies the focus/blur styles.

Comment: @JulioPérez yes, okey when an input is focus the placeholder (span) goes up then if you click outside the input the placeholder goes down to the center of the input, my issue here is that when i click outside the window (chrome) it does the expected behave it goes down beacouse the input lost focus but when i click inside again of the window the input get Focus and the FocusOut for some reason. (It goes up and down) like the gif. But when the input lose focus inside the window (when i click inside the same page) it works good.

Comment: @GerardoRodriguez It's because you capture the element right in the onfocus event but you aren't defining which element will you capture on the onblur event. That's why (I believe) this is happening

Comment: @JulioPérez I edited my question.

Comment: @GerardoRodriguez Are you implementing any kind of framework? because the code throws some errors

Comment: @JulioPérez jquery, bootstrap. You can delete this Html.GetFieldPlaceHolderText in the html and add any string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

CSS:

```
input.inp {
    padding: 18px 5px 4px 5px;
    background: none;
}

input.inp ~ label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: text;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    font-weight: 300;
}

input.inp ~ label.error {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: 0;
}

input.inp ~ label.active {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    top: 4px;
}

.group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
    <input class="inp">
    <label class="label">Label</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('input.inp').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).siblings('.label').addClass('active');
    });
    $('input.inp').on('blur', function () {
        $(this).siblings('.label').removeClass('active');
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $(this).siblings('.label').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.label').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```